# Flutter cannot build release apk got " Android resource linking failed"

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Am able to build debug apk but got this error for creating release apk.

```
[+17902 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':flutter_exif_rotation:verifyReleaseResources'.
[        ] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
[        ]    > Android resource linking failed
[        ]      ERROR:C:\Users\app\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\534b95f651786cc8f7db1990724e58bd\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:3:5-118: AAPT: error: resource
color/androidx_core_secondary_text_default_material_light (aka io.flutter.plugins.flutterexifrotation:color/androidx_core_secondary_text_default_material_light) not found.
[        ]      ERROR:C:\Users\app\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\534b95f651786cc8f7db1990724e58bd\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:14:5-18:13: AAPT: error:
resource color/androidx_core_secondary_text_default_material_light (aka io.flutter.plugins.flutterexifrotation:color/androidx_core_secondary_text_default_material_light) not found.
[        ]      ERROR:C:\Users\app\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\534b95f651786cc8f7db1990724e58bd\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:14:5-18:13: AAPT: error:
resource dimen/notification_action_text_size (aka io.flutter.plugins.flutterexifrotation:dimen/notification_action_text_size) not found.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 3m 34s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `flutter clean` resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should open the android project (look for `android` inside the project directory) in android studio refer [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynVMt.png)

Then, you can get a correct error, after you fix all issues related android environment on the android project type, build success, you can back to the flutter project and work as usual